# Implementing a linked list but the function that generates a new list containing only even numbers is wrong

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, initialization, singly-linked-list

I implemented a linked list. the filter_even-function should creat a new linked list which only includes even numbers. But somehow, when calling the print function is second time the new list also includes two random numbers. Output looks like this:

> 1       2       3       4
> 4       2       6422356 1528349827.

Can anybody please explain to me where I went wrong?

```
struct le{
    int value;
    struct le *next;
};

typedef struct le listenelement;

typedef listenelement *list; 

void insert(int v, list * l){
    listenelement *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(listenelement));
    new->value = v;
    new->next = *l;
    *l = new;
}
void print_list(list l){
    if (l == NULL) printf("Die Liste ist leer");
    else
        while (l->next != NULL){
            printf("%d\t", l->value);
            l = l->next;
        }
    zv;
}

void delete_all(list * l){
    list next;
    while (*l != NULL){
        next = (*l)->next;
        free(*l);
        *l = next;
    }
}

int position_of(int v, list l){
    int i = 0;
    while (l->next != NULL){
        if (v == l->value){printf("Der Wert %d erscheint in der Liste an der %d. Stelle (Index i = %d).", v, i + 1, i);
        return i;
        }
        i = i + 1;
        l = l->next;
    }
    printf("Der Wert %d erscheint nicht in der Liste.", v);
    return -1;
}

list filter_even(list l){
    list l_even; 
    int e;
    while (l->next != NULL){
        if ((l->value)%2 == 0){
            e = l->value;
            insert(e, &l_even);     
        }
        l = l->next;
    }
    print_list(l_even);  
    return 0;
}
int main(){

    list l1;
    int a = 4;
    insert(a, &l1);
    int b = 3;
    insert(b, &l1);
    insert(2, &l1);
    insert(1, &l1);
    print_list(l1);

    filter_even(l1);
    zv;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this `zv` sprinkled around the code?

Comment: ah sorry. It's a pre-defined "\n"

Comment: `typedef listenelement *list;` If you typecast pointers like this It makes it very difficult to read the code and understand what is and is not a pointer.

Comment: Probably just say `puts("")` instead.

Comment: yea i get that. Had a hard time understanding it as well. But this is actually from my professor and I had to write it like this, because it's part of a project :/

Answer (score 3):

For starters the pointer `l1` was not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
list l1;
```

As a result the program has undefined behavior.

You need to initialize it like

```
list l1 = NULL;
```

The condition like this in the while statement

```
    while (l->next != NULL){
```

does not make a sense. Due to the condition the last node of the list is ignored.

You need to use the following condition

```
    while ( l != NULL){
```

For example the function `print_list` should look like

```
void print_list(list l){
    if (l == NULL) printf("Die Liste ist leer");
    else
        while ( l != NULL){
            printf("%d\t", l->value);
            l = l->next;
        }
}
```

Pay attention to that within the function (and within main) there is a typo

```
zv;
```

Again within the function `filter_even` there is used an uninitialized pointer

```
list l_even;
```

You have to write

```
list l_even = NULL;
```

And the while loop has to be

```
while (l != NULL){
```

instead of

```
while (l->next != NULL){
```

And moreover the function return type is `list` but the function returns `0` (that is a null pointer) that does not make a sense.

```
return 0;
```

The return statement must look like

```
return l_even;
```

And in main you should write

```
list l_even = filter_even(l1);
```

And do not forget to free the lists.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code even makes more sense to me now :)